# AWS parse error: Invalid numeric literal

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to remove a user from AWS via a bash script.

The result I get back is:

```
Removing user_one from all groups.
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7
```

The name of the group I am trying to remove the user from is: grp-cloudops

This is my code:

```
  aws iam remove-user-from-group --user-name user_one --group-name grp-cloudops --profile=nonprod
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider reducing the code down to the part that fails. For example, can you reduce it down to a single `aws iam remove-user-from-group` command by substituting the relevant values?

Comment: ok done. Thanks!